# Manipulating dates column in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column with date type.
It contains data of this format:

```
09-02-2015 19:50
08-03-2015 20:26
09-03-2015 18:58
14-03-2015 15:47
```

I want to find all records which their date is `14-03-2015`

How do I remove the time?!

I tried:

```
select * from tab where strftime('%d-%m-%Y', date)='14-03-2015';
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: select * from tab where date(datecolumn)='2015-03-14';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date()` function:

```
where date(date) = '2015-03-14'
```

Always use ISO/ANSI standard formats for dates, YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: When I do for example: select date(date)  from tab  I get 800 rows (all rows in the table) with value NULL in all of them. Its not working

Comment: Gordon, This is how I get the data from API and save it in my DB I have no control over it. Some way or another I'll need to convert it. I'm open for suggestions. I don't mind saving it as YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM but again for doing it i'll need to do a conversion. Either way something needs to be converted.

Comment: @aaa . . . Perhaps your column is stored as a string and not in a date format.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't have a data type for dates, so your column is probably of type `text`.  Then you can compare the first 10 characters:

```
where substr(date, 1, 10) = '14-03-2015'
```

Comment: When I created the column I declated date type. This is also what i see in type column on my DB.

Comment: [SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) Are you sure you're using SQLite?